# Counting cells with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to believe I'm close to being able to count cells, but I also know I'm missing something.

I have this image

[image: Original image with cells]

```
image = cv2.imread('/cells.png', 
                cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = cv2.resize(image, (1000, 600)) 

th, threshedImg = cv2.threshold(image, 30, 255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshedImg, (3,3), 0) 
sobelxy = cv2.Sobel(src=img_blur, 
                    ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, 
                    dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, 
                  threshold1=20, 
                  threshold2=65)

cv2.imshow('thresh', threshedImg)
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Edge output:

[image: Image of edges.]

Threshold output:

[image: Image after threshold]

The threshold image captures the cells pretty good from what I can tell, and the Canny does a pretty good job for getting the edges. Ive tried making use of contours, but I was unable to produce any good results.

Any help or ideas on how to improve would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Analyze the individual color channels and you should be able to come up with a better approach

Comment: Thanks, Ill give that a try. Is that related to HSV strategies?

Comment: exactly, you can look into individual channels of HSV or LAB color space

Comment: Suggest LAB. The A channel is the green-red channel. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space. I suggest you threshold that channel appropriately. Then use morphology to close them up if needed. Then get contours and filter on area if desired

Comment: canny is a dead-end here. don't do that. -- messing around with color spaces is also pointless. this is basically a grayscale image. there's no information encoded in the color at all. -- blur it a little more, then look for local maxima, using `cv.dilate(img...) == img` as a mask of local maxima, combined with some absolute thresholds. -- note that the intensity of your picture is uneven, dimmer in the top right. you might have to deal with that

Comment: since you're new here, perhaps you'd benefit from taking the [tour]

Answer (score 3):

I count 286 blobs. That depends on some tweakables because some blobs that could be counted separately are really close together.

[image: result]

Approach:

- Your input has some grayish background in the bottom right. To compensate, I estimate the background using a large median blur, kernel size ~100, and subtract that (saturating math).
- Next, I blur the entire thing to suppress noise sufficiently that each blob is smooth (just one local maximum on it, no camel humps or worse)
- Then I use `image == cv.dilate(image, iterations=15)` to calculate a mask of ***local extrema***.
- Then I combine that with a mask of ***peaks*** which is simply `image > threshold`.
- I `&` (and) both masks together.
- morphological close/dilate operation to merge some peaks that occur due to numerics (anything the smoothing hasn't smoothed enough that the dilate and equality only see one peak)
- Then I use `connectedComponentsWithStats` to find all those blobs and their centroids.

My opinion on other approaches:

- Canny, makes absolute no sense at all. Will leave you in a worse place.
- Color Space transformation... pointless because your input is basically monochrome and I treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks for this! Im going to try it out and Ill let you know how it goes, but based on the image you posted this seems very promising!

Comment: make yourself a gui with cv.createTrackbar so you can fiddle with the various radii and see the intermediate results. it's definitely not perfect but I guess if you get to within ~1% of the truth that's usually good enough for science.

Comment: `@Christoph Rackwitz`.  Would you post your code, please.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/4894db73b3aa45a330c838619a75bba0